# For loop skipping the signal emit/slots

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, signals-slots

I am trying to call a function 'calculate' in my for loop, but when I run this code it skips the code 'self.stream.emit()' and continues the for loop. I have tried sleep and I dont have much knowledge about threading so tried that code how to pause the for loop,call the other function and then continue the loop

```
self.stream.connect(self.calculate)
stream = Signal()
def automated_process(self):
    for x in range(0, len(self.get_data)):
        self.pan_angle = self.get_data[x][0]
        self.tilt_angle = self.get_data[x][1]
        self.pass_excel_values.emit("self.pan_angle","self.tilt_angle")
        time.sleep(10)            
        self.stream.emit()            
        #t = threading.Thread(target=self.setup_camera)
        #t.start
```

Comment: from where are you calling the `automated_process()` method? Python will not magically skip over a line until told to.

Comment: self.connect(self.cycle_start,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.automated_process)       This is a function in my PySide GUI , I have called automated_process, my issue is not about calling the function but why emit is not working inside the for loop

Comment: What does `self.stream.emit()` do? Is there a way to know that the `emit()` function has executed or not.